# Passing host to link_to

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to send a link in an email, using a partial:

```
$html = $this->getPartial('templates/myTemplateHtml', array('id'=>$id));
```

_myTemplateHTML

```
<p><?php echo link_to('Moderate Template', '@template_moderate?id='.$id); ?></p>
```

When I receive the email, I get the `Moderate Link`, how do I modify the `link_to()` to include the URL that the email was sent from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the full link to your host, you should [enable the absolute option](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_link_to):

> - 'absolute' - if set to true, the helper outputs an absolute URL

This will give you this:

```
link_to(
  'Moderate Template', 
  '@template_moderate?id='.$id, 
  array('absolute' => true)
);
```